# Is it possible to run multiple tests in parallel on same browser (IE) using Selenium Grid?

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

I have a selenium java code which executes tests on IE. I want to try executing these tests in parallel using the same browser. How can I achieve this? And will I need to use multiple nodes to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup a selenium grid which has atleast 2 nodes attached to it.

When it comes to IE support, you can run ONLY 1 test at any given point in time on one selenium node.

So if you need to run two parallel IE tests, then you would need to have atleast 2 nodes attached to your grid.

This blog post of mine gives you a complete overview of the selenium grid.

https://rationaleemotions.github.io/gridopadesham/